# Why did Microsoft put close and minimize buttons on the Office splash screens?

Tags: controls, splash-screen

Starting with Office 2010, Microsoft put a minimize and close button on the upper right corner of the splash screens of the various Office apps. But, the splash screen is up for such a short time, what is the reason for doing this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Microsoft Office suite appears to have put a greater emphasis on Add-Ins. For default installations, none are included hence the splash screen only stays up for a very short time.

However, for Office power users, they may have many Add-Ins (especially enterprise users who develop their own custom AddIns) which will significantly slow the startup time when the plug-ins run.

AddIns are not controlled or regulated by MS so they may load for a very long time running code, performing updates etc.

Here's what my Excel with 1 Add-in looks like:

[image]

The close and minimise button was probably added to enhance the UX, **to allow the user to close Office should they accidentally open it, or let their Add-ins run perform updates in the background** etc.

Comment: and because a splash screen that stays in the foreground for 2 minutes while you are trying to work on something is annoying

Comment: From my experience working with in house applications, some splash screens stay on top for 5 minutes and cannot be reduced or hidden, it's the most annoying thing. Good job microsoft, hopefully that will become a best practice.

Comment: Just curious... wouldn't a splash screen which isn't kept in the foreground be enough? Possibly add the X to allow a user to stop the application from loading.

Comment: ^ Sometimes you just want to get rid of it.

Comment: It's not just addins.  A multi-GB PST file and thrash the HD to death corporate bloatware running at startup can bog an Outlook start down for a minute or two even without anything added to it.

Comment: @Shaamaan if you can't minimize it, it's blocking access to part of your desktop which is a problem for people who use it as an app/file launcher.

Comment: Ahh, very good point.

Comment: Ansd if you look thé splash with eyes you look à popup you just want to close thé popup (splash) by clicking on thé cross and so It is a mistake  because It closes the entIre software

Comment: I've actually found that the "x" on the splash screen is very misleading.  I expect it to close the splash screen, not cancel loading the application.  I've clicked the "x" a few times to get the splash screen out of my face only to realize "Crap! I just closed the application!"

Comment: Ah, I don't use any add-ins with my Office apps, so I can see how this would be helpful now. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If your computer is slow/the application is taking too long to load, you have the option to minimize or close the launch of the application. It is all about making the **user feel in control at all times**. Most of the time the user has no control if he launches the application, look at adobe suit, the applications take a while to load and there is nothing you can do to close them if you launched them accidentally. The splash screen controls help you bypass this problem.